# How to auto-close a telerik RadDateTimePicker on selected date

Tags: wpf, telerik, telerik-datepicker

The control is declared as follows :

```
 <telerik:RadDateTimePicker InputMode="DateTimePicker"
                            IsTabStop="False"
                            Height="36"
                            Focusable="False"
                            Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}"
                            SelectionOnFocus="SelectAll"
                            x:Name="OutwardStartDate"
                            BorderThickness="2,2,2,2"
                            SelectedValue="{Binding OutwardDepartureDate, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true,
                                                                     NotifyOnValidationError=true}" >
```

I've failed to find any XAML attributes in order to auto-close this control when a date is selected. I've stumble upon [this post on the official website](http://www.telerik.com/forums/auto-close-when-time-selected), however the question is dated from 5 years ago and none of the current answers solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply hook to the **SelectionChanged** event.

In your XAML as follows :

```
<telerik:RadDateTimePicker InputMode="DateTimePicker"
                           SelectionChanged="RadDateTimePicker_SelectionChanged"
                           IsTabStop="False"
                           Height="36"
                           Focusable="False"
                           Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}"
                           SelectionOnFocus="SelectAll"
                           x:Name="OutwardStartDate"
                           BorderThickness="2,2,2,2"
                           SelectedValue="{Binding OutwardDepartureDate,
                                               Mode=TwoWay,
                                               ValidatesOnDataErrors=true,
                                               NotifyOnValidationError=true}">
```

and in the code behind change the **IsDropDownOpen** property :

```
private void RadDateTimePicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AddedItems != null)
    {
        var dateTimePicker = sender as RadDateTimePicker;
        dateTimePicker.IsDropDownOpen = false;
    }
}
```